# Ajax call not populating table

Tags: php, ajax, database, asynchronous

I'm trying to populate my table using the so-called modern method of update parts of a website asynchronously using Ajax. I've managed to populate a table using pure php so far. Here's the code. Thanks in advance for your hints to solve this problem!

```
function showUsersBasic(){
$.ajax({
        url: 'php_dbrequests\php_requests.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
                $('#db-table-users').append(output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    }
```

Here is the code in php_dbrequests\php_requests.php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
$sql = "SELECT id, email, regdate FROM users";
$records = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$records->execute();
$results = $records->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $output_string = '';
    $output_string .=  '<table>';
    $output_string .= '<tr>';
    $output_string .= '<th>ID</th>';
    $output_string .= '<th>Email</th>';
    $output_string .= '<th>Register Date</th>';
    $output_string .= '</tr>';
foreach( $results as $row ){
    $output_string .=  "<tr><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['id'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['email'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['regdate'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  "</td>";
    $output_string .=  "</tr>";
}
    $output_string .= '</table>';
echo json_encode($output_string);?>
```

I know I got the very basic covered: my db connection is successful, the button calling ajax function works. I double checked my the reference to my table. Please, any hints will be very appreciated!

Comment: in chrome dev tools, go to network tab and make the ajax call, it will show if it's returning the expected results or error.

Comment: can you explain the unexpected behavior that has led you to post this please?

Comment: @WEBjuju After hitting the submit button, the contents of my table will not populate. No error message is returned either. But I have validated that at the very least the reference to the ajax function in the button works.

Comment: is there an element in the HTML with `id` attribute matching **db-table-users**?

Comment: @ flauntster I don't have chrome install. I'm using Mozilla Firefox to run the project. Do you know of any homologous option in it?

Comment: [code]                               <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="db-table-users" class="table table-bordered table-hover"></table>  
                                </div>
                            </div>[code]     I realized I had missed a </div> and I had my hopes it would work but that wasn't the actual problem. I'm using Bootstrap btw.  @WEBjuju

Comment: i'd guess that you can't append a table to a table.  also, below, one of the solutions is properly pointing out that you aren't sending back json, just html.  so you can remove the dataType json (and remove the php json_encode()) and then do something like they are doing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739105/using-jquery-ajax-function-with-datatype-html (and also stop adding a table to another table in the dom :)

Comment: @andrew use firebug extension's console to see ajax request and response

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your php code to return an array with some key like `data` and dont return `table` as you already have a `table` in your html. So just return `tr` with populated data.

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
$sql = "SELECT id, email, regdate FROM users";
$records = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$records->execute();
$results = $records->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $output_string = '';
    #$output_string .=  '<table>';
    $output_string .= '<tr>';
    $output_string .= '<th>ID</th>';
    $output_string .= '<th>Email</th>';
    $output_string .= '<th>Register Date</th>';
    $output_string .= '</tr>';
foreach( $results as $row ){
    $output_string .=  "<tr><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['id'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['email'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  $row['regdate'];
    $output_string .=  "</td><td>";
    $output_string .=  "</td>";
    $output_string .=  "</tr>";
}
    #$output_string .= '</table>';
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$output_string) );?>
```

Then modify your ajax code as :

```
function showUsersBasic(){

            console.info('showUserBasic called');  

  $.ajax({
    url: 'php_dbrequests\php_requests.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output_string){
            //OPEN FIREFOX FIREBUG EXTENSION & check console and click the ajax request to see its response
            console.log(output_string);           

            $('#db-table-users').append(output_string.data);
        } // End of success function of ajax form
    }); // End of ajax call   
 }
```

Comment: Got the same unresponsive behavior. I think it's something from the bigger picture I'm missing (besides my obvious lack of expertise).

Comment: I updated the ajax code
Can you check the response of above code in firebug extensions console? Let me know what is the output.

Comment: Just got the plugin installed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: press f12 once you have opened your project url. Then click on "console" tab and there once you do your ajax based action a request is shown, click on that and you can see its response and other details in specific tabs

Comment: I would be glad if you could upvote my answer if it has helped

Comment: I got something.. http://localhost/onPoint/php_dbrequestsphp_requests.php is 404 , cause: js xhr, type: html..wait but that was with my original code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129416/discussion-between-shivgre-and-andrew-redican).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `$.get()` function to get your PHP data using ajax.

```
function showUsersBasic() {
    $.get("php_dbrequests\php_requests.php", function(output_string, status){
        $('#db-table-users').append(output_string);
    });
 }
```

Comment: I've replaced the code I had with that and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

What's failing here?  Can we get more context?  Double check you selector (class vs. id)

Use the dev tools to ensure you're getting a response in the ajax call - or - add `alert(response);` to your success function.

*Doh! - try alerting on the response.  If all is working you should see your response from the php script here.

Comment: I replaced the function with the alert(output_string); I don't have any error or action displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
success: function(response){
                $('#db-table-users').append(response.output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    }
```

Comment: Like other suggestions, no errors or actions are shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should remove the parameter "dataType" from you ajax call code. You are expecting JSON but it is returning html.  You'll also need to remove the `json_encode()` from the echo in the php.