# Response from PHP to JS doesn't work after switching to JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I am developing my own blog type of website, and I bumped into a problem recently while trying to get rid of JS from my code. So I have show.js and showpost.php. Here is my JS code that was showing blog posts while I was using ajax js:

```
  load: function () {
    posts.ajax({ req: "show" }, function () {
      document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = this.response;
    });
  },
```

everything worked just fine. But when I tried to replace that with a JQuery version

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'app/showpost.php',
  dataType: 'text',

  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("okokok");
    document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = this.response;           
  }
});
```

it doesn't work how it's intended!
Now to explain how my showpost.php file works:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
echo('');
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `name`, `likes`,`imagename`,`comment_id`, `timestamp`, `message` FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id`=? ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
   $stmt->execute([$_POST['pid']]);

  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
  }

  while ($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)) { 
?>
<div id="post" style="box-shadow: 0 .15rem 1.75rem 0 rgba(58,59,69,.15)!important;">
<button id="<?=$r['comment_id']?>" name="like" class="btn" style="  float: right;" action="likepost.php" method="post"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><g><rect fill="none" height="24" width="24" y="0"/></g><g><g><path d="M13.12,2.06L7.58,7.6C7.21,7.97,7,8.48,7,9.01V19c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h9c0.8,0,1.52-0.48,1.84-1.21l3.26-7.61 C23.94,10.2,22.49,8,20.34,8h-5.65l0.95-4.58c0.1-0.5-0.05-1.01-0.41-1.37C14.64,1.47,13.7,1.47,13.12,2.06z M3,21 c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2v-8c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2s-2,0.9-2,2v8C1,20.1,1.9,21,3,21z"/></g></g></svg></button>
  <date><?=$r['timestamp']?></date>
  <h4>Bugs: <?=$r['likes']?></h4>
  <h3><?=$r['name']?></h3>
  <div class="message">
    <?=$r['message']?>
  </div>
  <img src="static/<?=$r['imagename']?>"> 
  </div>
 
  <?php }
  $stmt = null;
  $pdo = null;  
?>
```

as you can see, its a Php file with a little of html. It worked fine when I was using Xhr, but now with Jquery it doesn't work! Please help!

EDIT:   `document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = data;` doesn't change anything, it might be a problem of my showpost.php not sending out the html part.

Comment: You still have `document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = this.response;` from your custom code, but you need `document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = data;` instead. (or jQuery: `$('#cwrap').html(data);`)

Comment: _Small Note_ You would benefit from testing that `$_POST['pid']` acually existsed before usig it in a query

Comment: I don't know what happened. But now with this it doesn't even show anything! It was undefined and now its nothing

Comment: PID exists and it works

Comment: You can inspect the xhr in the console. Also, you're logging the result and okokok, can you see that?

Comment: Yes Chris. I can see it.

Comment: Only okokok. The result is blank

Answer (score -1):

datatype needs to be html or json

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'app/showpost.php',
  dataType: 'HTML',

  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("okokok");
    document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = this.response;           
  }
});
```

Comment: Not true, and there's no such thing as a "JSON object".

Comment: Even with HTML it shows undefined. I think its maybe a problem with Jquery or something?

Comment: yeah sorry only 'JSON'

Comment: try document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = data;

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here in your `success(data)` callback function.

```
  document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = this.response;
```

You are getting `data` but you are using `this.response` which is going to be undefined because there is no such variable defined. Also the dataType in ajax call should be html i.e., `dataType : 'html',`.
So it should be like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'app/showpost.php',
  dataType: 'html',
  
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("okokok");
    document.getElementById("cwrap").innerHTML = data;           
  }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think its a problem with the PHP file.

Comment: Check the api `'app/showpost.php'` on postman then if its giving the desired output or not because the jQuery code looks fine to me

Comment: And also keep the datatype as html i.e., `dataType : 'html',` Check this for more  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739105/using-jquery-ajax-function-with-datatype-html