# Flask render_template after AJAX call on button click doesn't render a page, nothing happens

Tags: python, flask

I have a templates folder with index.html and results.html and a static folder with a folder player_faces with images, names.csv for information matching and styles.css. And at the root I have a main.py file. The player_averages print perfectly fine on the line just before rendering the results template. Why isn't the template for results.html rendered?

This is the relevant part:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    # Get the data from the AJAX request
    data = request.get_json()

    # Connect to the database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Loop over the data and insert each record into the database
    for record in data:
        dropzone_id = record['dropzone_id']
        data_image = record['data_image']
        data_player_name = record['data_player_name']
        c.execute("INSERT INTO player_real (dropzone_id, data_image, data_player_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (dropzone_id, data_image, data_player_name))

    # Calculate the average dropzone ranking for the 8 players
    player_averages = {}
    for record in data:
        player_id = record['data_image']
        c.execute("SELECT AVG(CAST(SUBSTR(dropzone_id, 10) AS INTEGER)) FROM player_real WHERE data_image = ?",
                  (player_id,))
        avg_ranking = c.fetchone()[0]
        player_averages[player_id] = avg_ranking

    # Commit the changes and close the connection
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    # Send to the Results Page
    return redirect(url_for('results', player_averages=player_averages))

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    # Get the player averages from the URL query parameters
    player_averages = request.args.get('player_averages')
    print(player_averages)
    return render_template('results.html', player_averages=player_averages)
```

Here is the Javascript in my index.html file for the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Collect the data-image and data-player-name attributes of all image boxes
    var data = [];
    $('.dropzone').each(function() {
      var dropzone_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).find('.imagebox').each(function() {
        var data_image = $(this).attr('data-image');
        var data_player_name = $(this).attr('data-player-name');
        data.push({
          'dropzone_id': dropzone_id,
          'data_image': data_image,
          'data_player_name': data_player_name
        });
      });
    });

    // Send an AJAX request to a Flask route that handles the database insertion
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/submit',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(response) {
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
     }
    });
  });
});
```

I started by directly rendering the template in the submit function but that did nothing either. Then I tried render_template_string but that also did not do anything. I do not know what else to try at this point.

Comment: When using AJAX, the server's response is not automatically processed by the browser. Please add information on how you implemented your call. Do you use a library and how is the response processed on the client side?

Comment: i added it to the post, thank you Detlef

Comment: You added a function for when the call completes successfully. Unfortunately, this function is empty. Thus, the server's response is not processed and the rendered template does not appear. In contrast to a normal call, the response is not automatically processed by the browser when using AJAX. The developer is forced to process the data himself. In your case this means that you have to add the rendered template to the existing page or replace existing parts.

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation! I will put my results page in index.html in this case.

Comment: Would this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739105/using-jquery-ajax-function-with-datatype-html